# Angular 6 Reactive Form Custom Validation on select dropdown element

Tags: angular, angular-forms, angular-validation

I have a reactive form, which contains a FormControl that is a  element. It is rendered in the template like:

```
<select name="{{ xxx }}" [formControl]="c">
  <option *ngFor="let item of stringArray" value="{{ item }}">{{ item }}</option>
</select>
```

It has a custom validator applied to it, that is meant to make the field required if a second FormControl has a value, and not otherwise (partner is the passed in second control):

```
if ((control.value == null || control.value === '') && (partner.value != null && partner.value !== '')) {
  return { 'RequiredPair': true };
} else {
  return null;
}
```

The validation works if I select something from the dropdown, then key a value and remove it from the paired number field. It does not work if I just mark that number field as touched, and it never works on the select field. I have a function to mark all FormControls in the form as touched, recursively, on attempted submission of the form.

The only time I could get it to work on the select is adding an || control.value === 'one of the options' to the validator and choosing that option.

I haven't had issues with custom validators before, I think it probably has something to do with the  but I can't figure it out.

Edit: [minimal implementation on stackblitz](https://angular-fgqxhe.stackblitz.io)

Comment: Can you provide a minimal working scenario of this on stackblitz? I don't quite understand this `The validation works if I select something from the dropdown, then key a value and remove it from the paired number field`.

Comment: So I have a row of fields (controls) of them, one is rendered as <select>... and another is <input type=number">. These either need to be both filled in, or neither. If I select one of the options from the <select>, then touch the <input>, the validation check does not get triggered. But if I put in a value, like 5, then delete it, it does run and shows as invalid

Comment: @Gunner I think this is a minimal working (of the problem) version: https://angular-fgqxhe.stackblitz.io

Comment: I have created a basic working form https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng-form-validators. Can you check if this is what you are looking for? FYI: 0 for number input is considered as invalid.

Comment: @Gunner while that wasn't exactly what I needed, I've been able to adapt what I have to suit it. I had to convert FormArrays to FormGroups and stuff around with the template accordingly etc, but ultimately it now works. So thank you!